# How to combine JPG-file and MP3-file to MP4-file using FileManager-Actions?

Tags: nautilus, ls, execute-command, nautilus-actions, nautilus-extensions

I just installed »FileManager-Actions«

Now i try to get a command working for combining a JPG-file (its always 1920x1080px) with a MP3-file into a MP4-file.

Normally is used this command in terminal to do this:

```
ffmpeg -r 1 -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i audio.mp3 -acodec copy -r 1 -shortest -vf scale=1920:1080 video.mp4
```

But i really don't understand how to make it possible with FileManager-Actions that i could simply select an JPG-file and a MP3-file an run a command on this to create MP4-file like in my command before.

I know i would have to change that »image.jpg« and »audio.mp3« in my command. But into what???

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Filemanager actions uses the same [placeholder symbols](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#exec-variables) as these used in .desktop launcher files. This can answer your question in what placeholder symbols to use.

`%F` is the placeholder that returns all selected files on separate lines. In the simplest, but not foolproof way, you will need to have the discipline to select first the audio file then the picture file (or vice versa). Then you read the first file from `%F` into a variable AUDIO and the second file into a variable PICTURE. Finally, you execute your command, substituting $AUDIO" for the audio file and "$PICTURE" for the image file. Use the quotes so spaces in file names are handled correctly.

To make it more foolproof, you may want to add some more code to have your script check and prepare before executing the actual command to join the files by reading and analyzing the list of files. This would also have the advantage of being able to select audio and picture file in any order, and would prevent unexpected issues if inappropriate files were selected.

Your script thus should:

- Check whether precisely two files are selected or quit with an error message (you can use `zenity` for this) if this is not the case;
- Identify which one is the video file and which one is the graphic (the `file` command is usefull here) and assign each of the file names to an appropriate variable, i.e. AUDIO for the music file and PICTURE for the image. Throw an error and quit if (one of) the selected files are not valid.

If all this is good, the script proceeds by executing the command.

Comment: Thank you very much! But ...

Call me stupid but i still don't know how do that. I mean i understand the theory of what you said. But i dont know the language to do that. I googled for an hour to find an answer but i can't find any.

Let's say with PHP i start at the point having an array $F containing two files, i could simpy write:

`$IMAGE = $F[0];`
`$AUDIO = $F[1];`
`ffmpeg -r 1 -loop 1 -i $IMAGE -i $AUDIO -acodec copy -r 1 -shortest -vf scale=1920:1080 video.mp4;`

But how could i read first or second line in an array %F here?? I just don't get it. :/